# JavaRx doOnNext not called after onErrorResumeNext

Tags: android, arrays, rx-java, rx-android

I've tried to loop throw items and do additional request for each item. the issue is there it a possibility that request returns an error but i need to continue requests and collect all data to list. but it looks like after `onErrorResumeNext` called no other data adds to list.

```
Observable<List<TestModel2>> observable = apiTest
            .performTest()
            .flatMapIterable(items -> items)
            .flatMap(testModel -> {
                Log.d("TestItemData", "testModel.userId = " + testModel.userId);
                if (testModel.userId < 5) {
                    return apiTest.performTest2(testModel.userId);
                } else {
                    return apiTest.performTest3(testModel.userId);
                }
            })
            .doOnNext(testModel2 -> {Log.d("TestItemData", "doOnNext --- " + testModel2.title);})
            .onErrorResumeNext(throwable ->{
                            Log.d("TestItemData", "onErrorResumeNext -------- ");
                            return Observable.empty();
                         })
            .toList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

in this example afret `performTest()` called I get 10 items that i need to loop throw and call  `performTest2()` that returns data 
and for some id's i called `performTest3()` that returns 404 exception.

a for result in logs i see all 10 `testModel.userId`s (from 1 to 10) but `doOnNext` calls until `onErrorResumeNext` calls only, so in the result list i can got 1 item or 2 or 3 items only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the `doOnNext` and `onErrorResumeNext` inside the `flatMap`:

```
Observable<List<TestModel2>> observable = apiTest
    .performTest()
    .flatMapIterable(items -> items)
    .flatMap(testModel -> {
        Log.d("TestItemData", "testModel.userId = " + testModel.userId);
        Observable<TestModel2> obs;
        if (testModel.userId < 5) {
            obs = apiTest.performTest2(testModel.userId);
        } else {
            obs apiTest.performTest3(testModel.userId);
        }
        return obs
            .doOnNext(testModel2 -> {
                Log.d("TestItemData", "doOnNext --- " + testModel2.title);
            })
            .onErrorResumeNext(throwable ->{
                Log.d("TestItemData", "onErrorResumeNext -------- ");
                return Observable.empty();
            });
    })
    .toList()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```